# Complex queries on JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Can i use complex queries on jpa @Query Annotations like these

```
@Query(value = "select json_build_object (
          "  'sanctioned_roi' , data ->> 'sanctionedRoi' ," +
          "  'calculated_emi' , data ->> 'calculatedEmi' ," +
          "  'cibil_score' , data ->> 'CibilScore' ," +
          "  'coborrower_bureau_score' , data ->> 'bureauScore' ," +
          "  'case_stage' , data ->> 'leadStatus' " +
          ") from table where data->>'processInstanceId'=:processInstanceId"
          ,nativeQuery = true)
  JSONObject findData(@Param("processInstanceId") String processInstanceId);
```

Comment: As long as it is a native query, you can write almost anything that the DB supports

Comment: if i am trying to get the data in jsonForm using JPA will i get a striingified JSONObject or a simple JsonObject

Comment: No idea but should be easy enough to try. Worst case, you get a string you need to parse.

Comment: See this if you can help 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74530089/data-type-of-column-in-jpa-fetching-through-native-query?noredirect=1#comment131585433_74530089