# Data type of column in JPA fetching through native query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table which looks like this

Table :

```
id | data
 1 | { "name" :"abc","class":"123"  }
 2 | { "name" :"def","class":"456  }
```

data type of id = varchar
data type of data = json

i am using native query in jpa like this

```
@Query(value =
            "select data from Table where id=:id"
            ,nativeQuery = true)
    JSONObject findData(@Param("id") String id)
```

My question is the native query going to return me a JSONObject or a jsonObject in stringified form.if it returns me stringified form should i change return type of native query like this

```
String findData(@Param("id") String id)
```

Comment: Why don't you try before you ask?

Comment: my code is schedule to deploy tomorrow for testing,so i wanted to be sure if i can make some changes beforehand.

Comment: And you don't have a development database ?

Comment: can you please provide the create statement of the table?

Comment: Create table(
id varchar(10),
data json
);

Comment: It is scheduled to deploy on  development tomorrow and i cannot deploy it today due to some issue

Comment: It will not return JSONObject. But I can't tell you what it will return. Why don't you create a small example project and try it yourself?

Comment: I have simply changed return type to Object and then I am converting Object to String and then that String to JSON.

Comment: what's the type of the object you get?

Comment: when i run the same query on db i get object of type json,i wanna be sure when i run this query on JPA i will also get a jsonObject back.